# ffmpeg - is there a way to -map 0:m:language:eng if it exists, otherwise use the default?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

If a source has '**eng**' as an audio track, use that, otherwise use the default or audio track zero?

Is this possible?

I have tried:

```
 -map 0:m:language:eng? -map 0:a:0?
```

But that ends up always using the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.  I don't think ffmpeg has this feature, so I ended up writing a .bat script to mimic it.  The script uses `ffprobe` to probe the media file.  For each stream, if there's a language attribute set and that language != "eng", omit it.  Otherwise, map all streams without language + those with "eng" language, and copy to basename-fixed.ext.

It's probably more complicated than it ought to be, but you might find it useful.  *shrug*

```js
@echo off

for %%I in (*.mkv *.mp4) do (
    setlocal
    for /f "delims=" %%x in (
        'ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries "stream=codec_name:stream_tags=language" -of flat "%%~I"'
    ) do set "%%~x"
    for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set streams') do (
        echo(%%a | find /i "language" >NUL && if /i not "%%~b"=="eng" (
            for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%p in ("%%a") do (
                for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%s in ('set %%p.%%q.%%r') do set "%%~s="
            )
        )
    )

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%x in ('set streams ^| find "codec_name"') do (
        if not defined map (
            set "map=-map 0:%%x"
        ) else set "map=!map! -map 0:%%x"
    )
    echo ffmpeg -i "%%~I" !map! -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "%%~nI-fixed%%~xI"
    ffmpeg -i "%%~I" !map! -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "%%~nI-fixed%%~xI"
    endlocal
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately ffprobe is an extra delay to get the information first. ffmpeg must be the worst code i've ever seen and worst api ever.